# Where and how to write this SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my SQL query and its running but I want to update a particular table column with this query so how and where I write update query?

```
public void Add()
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("server =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = Online Medical Store ; integrated security = true");
    sqlcon.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select LastName, FirstName, FatherName, Address, City, Contact, EmailAddress,BookSubject,BookTitle,EditionNumber,ISBN_Number,Issue_Date from IssueBooks where StudentID =@studentID and " +
        "ISBN_Number = @isbnNumber", sqlcon);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studentId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISbnNumber", ISbnNumber);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        throw new Exception(" One Student Can Take Only One Book ");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = Online Medical Store ; integrated security = true");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("insert into IssueBooks(StudentID,LastName,FirstName,FatherName,Address, City," +
            " Contact, EmailAddress, BookSubject, BookTitle,EditionNumber, ISBN_Number,Issue_Date)values" +
            "(@studentID,@lastName,@firstName,@fatherName,@address,@city, @contact,@emailAddress,@BookSubject, @BookTitle, @EditionNumber, @ISBN_Number,@IssueDate)", con);
                                          
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studentId);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", LastName);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", FirstName);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fatherName", FatherName);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Address);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", City);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", Contact);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", EmailAddress);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookSubject", bookSubject);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookTitle", bookTitle);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EditionNumber", EditionNumber);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN_Number", isbnNumber);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueDate", Issue_Date);

        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    sqlcon.Close();
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on what you're trying to do? There are two queries here: select and insert. Are you thinking of changing the method from `Add` to `AddOrUpdate`?

Comment: BTW. Just one book is quite harsh. My local library allows up to 20 items these days.

Comment: Yes there are 2 queries but I want to add another update query in this section so please tell me how and where I add update query, I want to update particular table column with update query. @tymtam

Comment: You're using MSSQL. Just use a [`MERGE INTO` query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: what is merge query please write how and where @llama

Comment: How: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-merge-to-do-update-and-insert-operations-on-a-target-table-by-using-a-derived-source-table)! Where: Where you need it...?

Comment: @llama in my case where I write update query?

Comment: Only you know _where_ you want to execute an update. Presumably you want to do it in the piece of code where you currently throw the exception? How did you even get your code to this stage?

Comment: after insert query I want to update a particular column of a table so my question is how and where I write update query? @llama

Comment: Why do you keep asking "where"? Write it where you logically need it to run. If this isn't an "if exists, update, otherwise insert" scenario then my suggestion of merge is no good. An [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-the-where-clause) is the way to go.

Comment: Other things to think about: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), specify parameter types and lengths. Don't hardcode connection string, put it in a settings file. Dispose connection and reader with `using`. Unnecessary to select all those columns if you only want an `exists` check. In any case, consider placing it all in one batch and returning an error code, especially as you have a race condition between your two queries. ...

Comment: ... If you want [an "Upsert"](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern), consider protecting against races [with `HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK`](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/01/31/upsert-race-condition-with-merge/)